# Specify converter on a field-by-field basis

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to be able to specify the type of Converter on a field-by-field basis. To that end I've created an annotation to specify the desired converter class to use. I have also created a class that implements GenericConverter and ConditionalConverter. I return null from `getConvertibleTypes` to indicate that I want to check all the source-to-pairs. Inside the `matches` method I will check if my custom annotation is present and then use the specified converter class. My issue is that when I call `save` the `matches` method is only being called with `Long` as the sourceType and `ObjectId` as the targetType. Am I approaching this the correct way?

```
public class ConvertWithConditionalConverter implements GenericConverter, ConditionalConverter {

  @Override
  public boolean matches(TypeDescriptor sourceTypeDesc, TypeDescriptor targetTypeDesc) {
      // Only ever gets called with Long and ObjectId
      System.out.println("Source: " + sourceTypeDesc.getName() + ", Target: " + targetTypeDesc.getName());
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public @Nullable Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
      // Returning null indicates all source-to-target pairs should be considered.
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Object convert(@Nullable Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceTypeDesc, TypeDescriptor targetTypeDesc) {
      // Never gets called
      System.out.println("Source: " + sourceTypeDesc.getName() + ", Target: " + targetTypeDesc.getName());
      return null;
  }
}
```

The annotation that I want to annotate fields with

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface ConvertWith {
  Class<? extends Converter> value();
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you add the code to your question as well

Comment: Have you considered using Reflection or are you doing that already in order to get the class properties to convert?

Comment: @computercarguy the issue is that for spring-data-mongodb, in the `matches` method the `TypeDescriptor`s haven't retained the annotations. There is a [jira ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-889) but it is 5 years old and hasn't had any comment. So, I'm not sure if it is a bug or if it was intended